# Regex for first part of a string to match repeated (consecutive or non-consecutive) character

Tags: regex, string

Basically I have a string and I want to find the shortest sub-string (including the beginning) that matches the repetition of a character N times, it doesn't matter if consecutive or not. I want to use it in Javascript.

**Example:** 
Let's figure out the character is '/' and we want it to match 5 repetitions.

For this string:
http://remote-computer.example.local/home/dev/proj/sdk/docs/index.html#/api

The matching string would be:
http://remote-computer.example.local/home/dev/

For this string:
////remote-computer/example/local/home

The matching string would be:
////remote-computer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
^((?:[^/]*/){5})
```

The sub-string you want will be catched in group 1.

In javascript you could do:

```
var re = new RegExp("^((?:[^/]*/){5})); // excape the slashes is not mandatory
```

or

```
var re = /^((?:[^\/]*\/){5})/; // here you have to excape the slashes
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          : begining of the string
(          : start capture group 1
  (?:      : start non capture group
    [^/]*/ : 0 or more any character that is not a slash, followed by a slash
   ){5}    : the non capture group occurs 5 times
)          : end of group 1
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast and it looks like it work. Could you explain what it does?

Comment: To make it work in JS the characters have to be escaped, anyway it works great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Javiere: See my edit. You don't have toescape the slash if you're using the regex constructor (`new RegExp("blah blah")`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?:.*?/){5}`. [See a demo here](https://regex101.com/r/unOSTo/2).

This matches the exact same substrings as Toto’s regexp but is shorter:

1. There’s no need to use `^`; regexps start matching at the beginning *by default*.
2. You don’t need a capture group because you want the whole match.
3. `.*?/` matches "*everything until the next `/`, including it*", which can also be written as `[^/]*/` like Toto did.

Comment: Although shorter, that expression also matches any other substring not containing the beginning

Comment: @Javiere What do you mean? Regexps always start matching at the beginning of the string. Can you give an example where this doesn’t work?

Comment: I mean that it matches any string containing the pattern and I needed that only matched from the beginning like the other answer does.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the other regexp works and this one doesn’t?

Comment: The capture group will not contains the five slashes.

Comment: No but the matching substring will. You don’t need to use a capture group here.

Comment: So, why are you using a capture group?

Comment: Since the question was just for a match. In my opinion capture group or not is unimportant. But with capture group it is easier to read for beginners.

Comment: I like your solution, but what makes you think it is faster?

Comment: Toto = 42 steps, yours = 363 steps

Comment: @Fallenhero I removed that assertion; it’s only 10% faster in Chrome.